# Windows Phone 8.1 ListView with only 2 columns and unlimte row

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm trying to make a Listview with 2 columns, exactly like this picture:

http://i62.tinypic.com/10mrd5x.png

(Items most be vertical and exactly like the picture)

I know about WrapGrid and I can use this

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" 
                  MaximumRowsOrColumns="2" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                  VerticalChildrenAlignment="Stretch" 
                  HorizontalChildrenAlignment="Stretch" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

but this is too bad for what I want! this makes unlimited Columns when items is more than of screen height(when add 100 items to listview)
but I want just only 2 columns with unlimite rows.

My questions is:
Is this possible?
if Yes how can I do it?

sorry for my poor english

Comment: Did you try to set the orientation of the WrapGrid to Vertical?

Comment: Yes, but it's worse! only 2 can be add in rows

Comment: i tried your code in a sample project and it rendered exactly as you expected, with two items per row, expanding vertically. can you post the full xaml for your page? perhaps something else is happening here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same thing in WP 7.8 using the ListBox. /this is the part of my old project. Sorry for large number of useless tags and parameters :)

```
<ListBox 
Height="573" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Name="MyWallslistBox" 
VerticalAlignment="Top"  
DataContext="{Binding}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
Tap="wallslistBox_Tap" 
Width="480" 
Margin="0,-10,0,0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel 
            Orientation="Horizontal" 
            Margin="10,10,0,0">
                <Image 
                Source="{Binding Image}" 
                Height="225" 
                Width="225" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                />
                <StackPanel 
                Orientation="Vertical" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                Margin="-227,-3,-10,0">
                    <StackPanel 
                    Background="#56000000" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    MaxHeight="225" 
                    Margin="2,3,0,0" 
                    Width="225" 
                    Height="225">
                        <TextBlock 
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                        MaxWidth="235" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        Text="{Binding Title}" 
                        Foreground="White" 
                        FontSize="24" 
                        Margin="10,4,0,0" 
                        />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel Width="480"  />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: thank you, this is better than I was want! it's responsive! Thanks.

Comment: It's surprising for me that this code can be useful :D